# How to specify Perl encoding in Vim?

Tags: regular-expression

For a buffer containing text "กขค" with UTF-8 encoding:

`:perldo s/ข/x/g` => "กxค"

but `:perldo s/[ข]/x/g` => "xx�xxxxx�".

How to specify Perl's encoding?

Note: Currently I have to use `%:!perl -C -Mutf8 -pe 's/[ข]/x/g'`